Action of $G/H$ to $H^1(H,M)$, group cohomology
Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a normal subgroup. Let $M$ be $G$module.
$G/H$ acts on $H^1(H,M)$ by $(\bar{\sigma}*X)(g):=\sigma X({\sigma}^{-1}g\sigma)$ where $X $ is cocycle in $H^1(H,M)$ and $\bar{\sigma}\in G/H$ is the image of $\sigma\in G$ in $G/H$(Is this definition correct ? ).
To check this is indeed action, we should confirm that 'when $\sigma \in H$, $\sigma X({\sigma}^{-1}g\sigma)=X(g)・・・(★)$.
This can be done as following.
$\sigma X({\sigma}^{-1}g\sigma)=\sigma (X({\sigma}^{-1})+{\sigma}^{-1}X(g\sigma))=\sigma X({\sigma}^{-1})+X(\sigma)+X(g)$.
By the way, $0=X(\sigma {\sigma}^{-1})=X(\sigma)+\sigma X({\sigma}^{-1})$, so  $\sigma X({\sigma}^{-1})=-\sigma$. Thus $\sigma X({\sigma}^{-1}g\sigma)=X(g)$.
So far, so good.
My question is, from (★), how can I prove the following ?

$\sigma_1≡\sigma_2 \text{mod}H\implies
(\bar{\sigma_1}*X)(g)=(\bar{\sigma_2}*X)(g)$.

As discussed here, I tried to prove this by cocycle conditions, but in vain.
Group action on cohomology is trivial

You need $M$ to be a $G$-module, not just a $H$-module.

By the way there are errors in the calculation part.
This formula is incorrect:
$$\sigma X(\sigma^{-1}) + X(\sigma) + X(g)$$
It should have been:
$$\sigma X(\sigma^{-1}) + gX(\sigma) + X(g)$$
Then the first two terms form a coboundary:
$$\sigma X(\sigma^{-1}) + gX(\sigma) = -X(\sigma) + gX(\sigma) = \delta(X(\sigma))(g)$$
As a result, they cancel in the cohomology group (but not at the cochain level).

＠Yes, it was mistake. Thank you for your correction.

Let $\Gamma$ be a group acting on a set $S$ and let $\Gamma'$ be a normal subgroup of $\Gamma$ (I'm using weird letters and using just set-actions and not module-actions to emphasize that this is pure group theory, you've already done the homology). I claim that the given action of $\Gamma$ on $S$ descends to an action of $\Gamma/\Gamma'$ on $S$ (i.e. $\gamma_1 s = \gamma_2 s$ whenever $\gamma_1^{-1} \gamma_2 \in \Gamma'$) if and only if $\Gamma'$ acts trivially on $S$.
For $\Rightarrow$, note that if $\gamma$ is equivalent to $e$, i.e. in $\Gamma'$, then $\gamma$ acts trivially, so all of $\Gamma'$  acts trivially).
For $\Leftarrow$, note that if $\gamma_1$ is equivalent to $\gamma_2$, then $\gamma_1^{-1} \gamma_2$ is in $\Gamma'$, so acts trivially on any $s$ in $S$. But then you can act on the left by $\gamma_1$ on both sides of $\gamma_1^{-1} \gamma_2 s = s$ to get the desired result.
(More conceptually, the action gives a map $\Gamma \to \text{Aut}(S)$ and $\Gamma'$ being in the kernel of this map is exactly the condition to say the map factors through $\Gamma/\Gamma'$, which is exactly the same as saying the action descends to an action of $\Gamma/\Gamma'$.)
(Your problem is specifically the case $\Gamma = G$, $\Gamma'= H$, $S = H^1(H, M)$, but again, the module structure on $M$ and the definition of $H^1$ don't matter at all for this very last step -- of course they matter in the step you've already done.)

I am deeply grateful for your thoughtful and meticulous effort in untangling my confusion and providing beautiful answers. Thank you so much.
